# Scala function sub type

Tags: scala

`type Fun1 = { val a: A } => { val b: B }`

`type Fun2 = { val b: B } => { val a: A }`

What I want to know is the super type of above types.

**Fun1 <: Common**

**Fun2 <: Common**

Comment: Is there any relationship between `A` and `B`? Do they have a common supertype?

Answer (score 7):

Since functions' input types are *contravariant*, and return types are *covariant*, the common input type is the "closest" common **subtype** of A and B (e.g. `A with B`), and the common return type is the "closest" **super type** of A and B (e.g. `Any`), so if we know nothing about A and B, the answer is:

```
A with B => Any
```

For example:

```
scala> class A
defined class A

scala> class B
defined class B

scala> type Fun1 = A => B
defined type alias Fun1

scala> type Fun2 = B => A
defined type alias Fun2

scala> val f1: Fun1 = (x: A) => new B()
f1: A => B = <function1>

scala> val f2: Fun2 = (x: B) => new A()
f2: B => A = <function1>

// both f1 and f2 can be assigned into a value of type A with B => Any
scala> val f3: A with B => Any = f1
f3: A with B => Any = <function1>

scala> val f4: A with B => Any = f2
f4: A with B => Any = <function1>
```

Comment: Functions are contravariant in their input type and covariant in output type

Comment: @dkolmakov oops - of course! my bad, thanks for correcting me